# SQL given two tables how we can select all of the columns from a table conditionally

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables and in UI we are expecting columns from only one table by passing a static condition. e.g. in table1 if sum('leave_till_date') is greater then 0 then pull data from table1 and if its 0 then pull data from table2.

We got to save this query in a table from where it will be getting fetched and run dynamically during run time.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simply write two queries conjoined by a UNION ALL and ensure they are mutually exclusive:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE (SELECT SUM(leave_till_date) FROM table1) > 0
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE (SELECT NVL(SUM(leave_till_date),0) FROM table1) <= 0
```

However, if the condition is variable, you'll need to use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` into a collection or a dynamic `REF CURSOR` (`sys_refcursor`) within a table function to dynamically construct the query with the condition of your choice. Here's the latter:

```
-- sample data
create table table1 (id number, emp_country varchar2(2), employee varchar2(3), leave_till_date number);
create table table2 (id number, emp_country varchar2(2), employee varchar2(3), leave_left number);

insert into table1 values (1,'US','ABC',0);
insert into table1 values (2,'US','XYZ',1);
insert into table2 values (1,'US','MNP',0);
insert into table2 values (2,'US','CVM',1);
commit;

-- create SQL object and table types
create type myobjtype is object (id number, emp_country varchar2(2), employee varchar2(3), leave number);
create type mytabtype is table of myobjtype;

-- create pipelined table function

create or replace function myfunction (in_condition IN varchar2)
  return mytabtype pipelined
as
  var_cursor sys_refcursor;
  var_rec myobjtype;
begin
  OPEN var_cursor FOR q'{SELECT myobjtype(id,emp_country,employee,leave_till_date)  FROM table1 WHERE }'||in_condition||q'{
                         UNION ALL
                         SELECT myobjtype(id,emp_country,employee,leave_left) FROM table2 WHERE NOT }'||in_condition||q'{
                       }';
                       
  FETCH var_cursor INTO var_rec;
  
  WHILE var_cursor%FOUND
  LOOP
    PIPE ROW (var_rec);
    FETCH var_cursor INTO var_rec;
  END LOOP;
  
  CLOSE var_cursor;
end;
```

Now use it:

```
select * from myfunction('(SELECT NVL(SUM(leave_till_date),0) FROM table1) > 0')
```